# pandasで'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'split'のエラーを解決したい

Tags: python, python3, pandas, csv

CSVからpandasで読み取った"/"で数字のまとまりごとに区切ってある文字列（OIDカラムの数字の文字列）をsplitで分割して再度、リスト化したいのですが、タイトルにあるエラーで上手く実装できません。
何かアドバイスを頂ければ幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

```
read_csvの結果
                                  OID
0    1618544796/1043253441/1468827215
1    1618544796/1043253441/1468827215
2    1618544796/1043253441/1468827215
3    1618544796/1043253441/1468827215
4    1618544796/1043253441/1468827215
..                                ...
197                               NaN
198                        1714135326
199                        1714135326
200                        1714135326
201                               NaN

[202 rows x 1 columns]
```

```
import pandas as pd

file0 = "./node_file2.csv"
file1 = "./node_file3.csv"

f0 = pd.read_csv(file0, usecols=[0])
f1 = pd.read_csv(file1, usecols=[0])
read_oid0 = pd.read_csv(file0, usecols=[11])
read_oid1 = pd.read_csv(file1, usecols=[8])

split_oid0 = read_oid0.split('/', expand =True)
print(read_oid0)
```

Answer (score 1):

この記事の応用で、column名を指定して.strを追加すれば良いでしょう。
[pandasの文字列を区切り文字や正規表現で複数の列に分割](https://note.nkmk.me/python-pandas-split-extract/)

以下のようになります。

```
split_oid0 = read_oid0['OID'].str.split('/', expand =True)
```

ただし、そうすると`NaN`とか`None`になるところも出てきます。
元がこんなデータだった場合、

```
                                OID
0  1618544796/1043253441/1468827215
1  1618544796/1043253441/1468827215
2  1618544796/1043253441/1468827215
3  1618544796/1043253441/1468827215
4  1618544796/1043253441/1468827215
5                               NaN
6                        1714135326
7                        1714135326
8                        1714135326
9                               NaN
```

こんな結果になります。

```
            0           1           2
0  1618544796  1043253441  1468827215
1  1618544796  1043253441  1468827215
2  1618544796  1043253441  1468827215
3  1618544796  1043253441  1468827215
4  1618544796  1043253441  1468827215
5         NaN         NaN         NaN
6  1714135326        None        None
7  1714135326        None        None
8  1714135326        None        None
9         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

必要ならば、この記事を応用して、空文字列なり`0`なりにすれば良いでしょう。
[pandasで欠損値NaNを除外（削除）・置換（穴埋め）・抽出](https://note.nkmk.me/python-pandas-nan-dropna-fillna/)

以下は空文字列にしています。

```
split_oid0 = split_oid0.fillna('')
```

こんな結果になります。

```
            0           1           2
0  1618544796  1043253441  1468827215
1  1618544796  1043253441  1468827215
2  1618544796  1043253441  1468827215
3  1618544796  1043253441  1468827215
4  1618544796  1043253441  1468827215
5
6  1714135326
7  1714135326
8  1714135326
9
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！無事実装することができました！頂いたURLも参考にさせて頂きます！