# ValueError: Length of values (2) does not match length of index (5) が起こる

Tags: python, pandas

pandasの `=` の動きを理解しないまま、推測でコードを書いています。

まず、下記のように書くと動くことが確認できました。

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'date': ['01-01', '01-02', '01-03', '02-01', '02-01'],
  'value': [10000, 5000, 1000, 500, 100]
})

df['group'] = df['date']

g_df = df.groupby('group')
g_df.head()
```

結果:
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

また下記のようにすると動くことも確認できました。

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'date': ['01-01', '01-02', '01-03', '02-01', '02-01'],
  'value': [10000, 5000, 1000, 500, 100]
})

df['group'] = '01-01'.split('-')[0]

g_df = df.groupby('group')
g_df.head()
```

結果:
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

なるほど。であれば、

```
df['group'] = df['date'].split('-')[0]
```

とすればうまくいくのかと思ったのですが、これはエラーになりました。

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'

うーん。文字列とおもっていたのにどうやら私が操作していたのは、`Series`のようだと思い、

[pandasで'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'split'のエラーを解決したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/66717/pandas%E3%81%A7dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-split%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%82%92%E8%A7%A3%E6%B1%BA%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)

を見てみて `str` というのがあるのかと思って下記を試しました。

```
df['group'] = df['date'].str.split('-')[0]
```

今度は、

> ValueError: Length of values (2) does not match length of index (5)

というエラーでした。

試しに、

```
df['group'] = df['date'].str

g_df = df.groupby('group')
g_df.head()
```

としてみると

結果:
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

となっており、`pandas`の文字列関係のオブジェクトが入っているよです。

どうすれば、各レコードごとのデータを文字列としてsplitで加工し、新しい列を追加できるのでしょうか？

Comment: `expand=True` を指定してみてはどうでしょう。`df['date'].str.split('-', expand=True)[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

例えばこちらの記事の回答に書いた最後の方法で出来ます。
[Excelの日付フォーマットを変換の回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/76083/26370)

こんな風になります。

```
df['group'] = df['date'].apply(lambda _: _.split('-')[0])
```

---

同様に@metroploisさんコメントの方法だとこちらになります。

```
df['group'] = df['date'].str.split('-', expand=True)[0]
```

---

他に分割した両方とも使いたい場合は、上記@metroploisさんコメントの方法を使って、単純には代入できないので`pd.concat`で元のdfと結合するという方法があります。
[pandasの文字列を区切り文字や正規表現で複数の列に分割](https://note.nkmk.me/python-pandas-split-extract/)

こんな風になります。

```
df = pd.concat([df,df['date'].str.split('-', expand=True)],axis=1)
df.rename(columns={0: 'group', 1: 'subgroup'}, inplace=True)
```